# Error al insertar datos con PDO y POO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Saludos comunidad. Estoy desarrollando una aplicación usando PDO, estoy comenzando y se me ha presentado un problema a la hora de insertar registros en la base de datos. A continuación coloco las funciones que estoy usando y el error que me esta dando.

Primero mi controlador recibe los datos de la siguiente manera:

```
public function agregar(){
        if(!$_POST){
            $datos = $this->seccion->listar();
            return $datos;
        }else{
            $permitidos = array("image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif", "image/jpg"); // valido los formatos de imagen permitidos
            $limite = 700;
            if(in_array($_FILES['imagen']['type'], $permitidos) && $_FILES['imagen']['size'] <= $limite * 1024){ //valido si el formato y el peso son aceptados
                $nombre = $_FILES['imagen']['name'] . date('is'); //creo el nombre de la imagen
                $ruta = "Views" . DS . "templates" . DS . "imagenes" . DS . $nombre; //asigno la ruta de la imagen
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'], $ruta);
                $this->estudiante->set("nombre" , $_POST['nombre']);
                $this->estudiante->set("edad" , $_POST['edad']);
                $this->estudiante->set("promedio" , $_POST['promedio']);
                $this->estudiante->set("imagen" , $nombre);
                $this->estudiante->set("id_seccion" , $_POST['id_seccion']);
                $this->estudiante->add();
                echo error_reporting();
            }
        }
    }
```

Luego esos datos los recibe la funcion set() que esta en mi models

```
public function set($atributo, $contenido){
        $this->$atributo = $contenido;
    }
```

La cual pasa esos datos a mi funcion add() en el modelo

```
        public function add(){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO estudiantes(nombres, edad, promedio, img, id_seccion)
        VALUES(:nombre, :edad, :promedio, :imagen, :id_seccion)";

        $params = [':nombre' => $this->nombre];
        $params = [':edad' => $this->edad];
        $params = [':promedio' => $this->promedio];
        $params = [':imagen' => $this->imagen];
        $params = [':id_seccion' => $this->id_seccion];

        $this->con->consultaSimple($sql, $params);

    }
```

Por ultimo ejecuto la query con esta funcion

```
public function consultaSimple($sql, $binds = []){
        $datos = $this->con->prepare($sql);

        foreach ($binds as $key => $val) {
            $datos->bindParam($key, $val);
        }

        $datos->execute();
    }
```

Esas son todas las funciones que utilizo para insertar, el error que me esta generando es el siguiente:

**Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in C:\xampp\htdocs\pdo\Models\Conexion.php on line 25
22527**

Aclaro que la linea en donde me arroja el error es en la función ConsultaSimple en el execute()
La verdad no he podido resolver este error y le he dado muchas vueltas ya y no he tenido exito.

Comment: creo que estas cargando $binds con un arreglo vacio. Con sólo colocar $binds en consultaSimple() ya debería solucionarse. en vez de $binds = [] coloca $binds como parametro de entrada en consultaSimple()

Comment: Saludos Huskie. He hecho lo que comentaste y sigue arrojando el mismo error!

Comment: Vuelve a como lo tenías antes y prueba a dar echo a $key y $val dentro de tu foreach. Porque según el error que te da parece que no esta viendo todos los parametros necesarios para realizar la inserción a la base de datos

Comment: he colocado los dos echo $key y $val y este es el resultado, ademas he puesto var_dum a $datos despues del execute mostrando lo siguiente:           :id_seccion1
Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in C:\xampp\htdocs\pdo\Models\Conexion.php on line 27
bool(false) 22527

Comment: es curioso los echo solo arrojan el :id_seccion1

Comment: seguro huskie..

Comment: Ok huskie. usare el bind en la funcion add y vere que tal funciona. ya te comento que es lo que ha pasado

Comment: Prueba con la respuesta que te coloque. Hay un problema con tu foreach por lo que dice el error de tu xampp. Además el foreach de la función consultaSimple redundas un poco debido a que puedes bindear de una vez los datos en la declaración en add en vez de declararlos para luego bindearlos es como repetir un poco el código. Copia el código nuevamente que edite mi respuesta.

Comment: Pero recuerda eliminar consultaSimple(); genera redundancia de código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Respuesta editada

Buen punto el acotado por @xerif en su comentario a esta respuesta, por lo que me retracto de lo siguiente:

<s>Creo que te estás ahogando en un vaso de agua. El problema es que en `consultaSimple($sql, $binds = [])` tú limpias tu array al hacer `$binds=[]`, o sea, la función interpreta que el parámetro es siempre un array vacío.</s>

En realidad, como bien dice Xerif, se estaba sobre-escribiendo el array y ese sería el principal motivo del error.

---

No obstante, mantengo mi respuesta en cuanto a lo que sigue:

1. No le veo demasiada utilidad a pasar el código a un método solamente para preparar y ejecutar la consulta, tomando en cuenta que `prepare` y `execute` son ya métodos propios de PDO.
2. Mucho menos le veo sentido a hacer el binding mediante un bucle `for` (aunque tienes toda la libertad para hacerlo de esa manera si así lo quisieras). Digo esto porque en PDO (y esa es una de sus maravillas con respecto a mysqli), **tú puedes pasar el array con los parámetros directamente en el `execute`, sin necesidad de usar `bindValue`**.
3. Me centraría más en mejorar la función `add`, por ejemplo, controlando lo que ocurre en ella, sus posibles errores y haciendo que devuelva un resultado, sea el número de filas insertadas o un mensaje de error. También la función `add` podría ser más global, dándole a ella, y no a `consultaSimple`, la posibilidad de recibir la instrucción SQL y los parámetros.

Por ejemplo:

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO estudiantes (nombres, edad, promedio, img, id_seccion) 
    VALUES (:nombre, :edad, :promedio, :imagen, :id_seccion)";
    /*Construimos el array de este modo, así evitaremos errores como el inicial*/
    $arrParams=array (  ':nombre' => $this->nombre, 
                        ':edad' => $this->edad, 
                        ':promedio' => $this->promedio, 
                        ':imagen' => $this->imagen, 
                        ':id_seccion' => $this->id_seccion);

    /*Pasamos al método add la consulta y los parámetros, recuperando en una variable su respuesta*/
    $intResultado=add($sql, $arrParams);

    /*Aquí podemos evaluar el resultado de la llamada, para fines de información*/
    if ($intResultado >0){
        //Se insertaron datos
    }else{
        //No se insertaron datos
    }



/*Una función de agregación que podemos usar con cualquier consulta insert*/
public function add($sql, $arrParams){
    /*Preparamos*/
    $stmt=$this->con->prepare($sql);

    /*
      *Ejecutamos pasando los parámetros recibidos
      *Quiero INSISTIR en este punto, porque es una de las grandes ventajas de PDO
      *en el método execute se pueden pasar los parámetros directamente
      *sin tener que abrir bucles o recurrir a procedimientos complicados
      *por ejemplo en el caso de consultas dinámicas
    */
    $insert=$stmt ->execute($arrParams);

    /*Usamos un operador ternario para saber lo que ocurrió en la consulta*/
    $intResultado = ($insert) ? $stmt->rowCount() : 0;

    /*La función devolverá 0 en caso de no inserción o de error, o el número de filas insertadas*/
    return $intResultado;
}
```

De este modo el método `add` se puede usar desde cualquier parte.

Comment: `consultaSimple($sql, $binds = [])` claramente esto no limpia el array, revise http://php.net/manual/es/functions.arguments.php por otro lado el metodo `consultaSimple()` tiene su logica si se quieren ejecutar diferentes sql con difetentes parametros.

Comment: @xerif no le veo ninguna lógica a tener un método para hacer lo que ya hacen métodos específicos de PDO, tales como `prepare` y `execute`, menos aún si en el `execute` se pueden enviar los parámetros sin tener que recurrir al bucle for que se está usando. Revisaré lo del parámetro igualado a `[]` y si tienes razón entonces modificaré la respuesta. Haciendo una lectura rápida del enlace que me indicas no veo en ninguna parte lo que dices en tu comentario. Haré una prueba de código y si tienes razón me retractaré de esa parte de la respuesta.

Comment: yo personalmente no lo haría así,  pero desconozco la intencionalidad del OP.  En cuanto al enlace aparece como: **valores de argumentos predeterminados**

Comment: Acabo de verlo @Xerif. Yo buscaba un ejemplo de código directamente, en una primera lectura rápida. Aunque se desconozca la intencionalidad del OP, me parece que en muchos casos se sub-estima el uso de PDO, usándolo como si fuera mysqli. Esta pregunta es un caso típico de lo que digo: **se recurre a un bucle for para hacer el binding, cuando los parámetros se pueden pasar directamente en el `execute`.** Insisto en eso en la respuesta, con la idea de que se aprenda a sacar el máximo provecho a PDO en vez de seguir usándolo como si fuera mysqli... **PDO no es mysqli, es mucho más.** Saludos.

Comment: Interesante todo lo que lei Cedano y Xerif. Con respecto a lo que dice Xerif eso es lo que quiero con el metodo consultaSimple(), ejecutar diferentes sql con diferentes parametros. Probare de las dos formas a ver cual responde de mejor manera.

Comment: @AlejoMendoza mi respuesta está orientada a que en tu aplicación tengas un método que te sirva para agregar cualquier fila a cualquier tabla... ese sería el método `add`... Esa es una forma de proceder en lo que se llama `CRUD`, de las iniciales **C**reate**R**ead**U**pdate**D**elete. En este caso el método `add` escrito más o menos como indico en mi respuesta, serviría para crear cualquier elemento en la BD, sin importar qué tabla o qué valores sean. Si creas métodos parecidos para leer (Read), para actualizar (Update)  y para borrar (Delete), ya tienes un CRUD montado en toda la app

Comment: Si entiendo lo que me explicas Cedano y tiene sentido. He hecho lo que me dijiste y el operador ternario esta devolviendo 0.

Comment: Estoy empezando a pensar que tengo problemas en mi controlador

Comment: @AlejoMendoza si devuelve `0` significa que la inserción no está ocurriendo. Tú puedes aún mejorar, si lo quisieras, el método `add`, creando un array con lo que ocurra dentro de él... no quise profundizar más en eso porque ya mi respuesta cambiaba bastante tu código inicial. Pero tú puedes por ejemplo capturar posibles errores que estén ocurriendo. Si en el operador ternario tu cambias el `0`  por algo como esto: `$stmt->errorInfo()[2]`, en vez de cero, te dirá qué error específico está ocurriendo en tu consulta (consulta errónea, violación de alguna restricción, etc).

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71017/discussion-between-alejo-mendoza-and-a-cedano).

Comment: @A.Cedano Deberías formar un libro amigo, dedicación de un poco de tiempo de hacerlo en cada respuesta que das, increíblemente admirado tanto en código como la explicación.

Answer (score 1):

Claramente el error esta en la función `add()` fijate que estas sobre escribiendo $param todo el rato, por lo que al final solo envías un único valor a `consultaSimple()`

Esta parte

```
    public function add(){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO estudiantes(nombres, edad, promedio, img, id_seccion)
    VALUES(:nombre, :edad, :promedio, :imagen, :id_seccion)";

    $params = [':nombre' => $this->nombre];
    $params = [':edad' => $this->edad];
    $params = [':promedio' => $this->promedio];
    $params = [':imagen' => $this->imagen];
    $params = [':id_seccion' => $this->id_seccion];

    $this->con->consultaSimple($sql, $params);

}
```

Debería quedar así

```
    public function add(){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO estudiantes(nombres, edad, promedio, img, id_seccion)
    VALUES(:nombre, :edad, :promedio, :imagen, :id_seccion)";

    $params[':nombre'] = [$this->nombre];
    $params[':edad'] = [$this->edad];
    $params[':promedio'] = [$this->promedio];
    $params[':imagen'] = [ $this->imagen];
    $params[':id_seccion'] = [$this->id_seccion];

    $this->con->consultaSimple($sql, $params);

}
```

Comment: Saludos Xerif, al probarlo de la forma en que me has dicho me arroja esto: Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\pdo\Models\Conexion.php on line 22
ese notice lo arroja 5 veces, que son la cantidad de datos que necesito guardar. La linea 22 es la que esta dentro del foreach, donde hago el $datos = bindParam($key, $val)